# Does MonoDroid support java.lang.reflect package methods?

Tags: reflection, xamarin.android

I need to use methods from `java.lang.reflect` in a MonoDroid solution, but I can't find this  namespace anywhere. Is there a way to access these?

Comment: What do you need it for? Can't you use C# Reflection?

Comment: I need to call Android private method.. to set "Data enable" in setings. Can i do this by C# Reflection?

Comment: I think best way to do this is actually write it in Java and bind it to your managed code through JNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java.lang.reflect package is not bound in Mono for Android. [This bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5111#c9) has some more details about that. If you really need to work around that limitation, you could write that part of your application in Java and then call it through JNI. Xamarin has a good guide on using JNI up [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Binding_Android_Types).