# Monodroid JNI for Java reflection to call a private method

Tags: c#, java, java-native-interface, xamarin.android, jnienv

In a Monodroid project, I need to be able to call a private method on a class.  From [an answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610875/362536), it seems that this is possible in Java via reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;

...

ParcelFileDescriptor pipe[] = null;

try {
    Method createPipeMethod = ParcelFileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredMethod("createPipe");
    pipe = (ParcelFileDescriptor[]) createPipeMethod.invoke(null);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I need to use this code from Monodroid.  Unfortunately, [`java.lang.reflect` is not available in Monodroid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376050/362536).  However, it has been suggested that I can run this code using JNI from my Monodroid project.  The [Xamarin documentation states that inline JNI is possible](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Java_Integration_Overview), without having to bind a whole JAR.  Unfortunately, [further documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Working_With_JNI) doesn't say anything more on the subject.  Furthermore, the [documentation on JNIEnv](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Runtime.JNIEnv) is blank.

It looks like I need `JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod()`, but I have no idea how to do it.  I can't find an example, or further documentation.

**How can I use `java.lang.reflect` in my Monodroid project, or in some other way call the private method `.createPipe` on `ParcelFileDescriptor`?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use C# reflection on `Android.OS.ParcelFileDescriptor`?

http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3AAndroid.OS.ParcelFileDescriptor

I did not yet try it, but if Mono for Android even wraps private members of a Java class, simply using C# reflection might be enough.

If this failed, you can pursue on the JNI attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with JNI: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/working_with_jni#_Static_Methods

A rough untested sketch:

```
var methodId = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(ParcelFileDescriptor.Class.Handle, 
                                        "createPipe", 
                                        "()[Landroid/os/ParcelFileDescriptor;");
var result = JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod(myCSharpFileDescriptorInstance.Handle,
                                           methodId);
```